# PHP/Tinymce issue, carriage returns displaying in the output

Tags: tinymce

I'm using tinymce on this page:

http://coachbrian.ca/CoachBrian4/admin/index.php?public=7&page=1

On that page the user can edit whatever text they want, which later gets viewed and displayed on this page:

http://coachbrian.ca/CoachBrian4/index.php?public=1

What's happening right now is that every time the user edits and saves whatever text they want, the next time they go in, there's a bunch of "rn"'s in the text.

I've used this in my PHP to try and clean them out:

```
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r", "rn", "rnrn", "<p>&nbsp;</p>");
$replace = '';

// Processes \r\n's first so they aren't converted twice.
$formatOne = str_replace($order, $replace, $unformattedText);
```

And then I save the entry in the database. I also use the same code on the the 'display' page that the public would see, and for some reason the "rn"'s don't show, but there's extra carriage returns.

I've been banging my head for 2 days now looking for what is probably an obvious issue but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like ppl ended up with the same solution: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=12092

Comment: Okay, I discovered what was causing my personal issue, it was sort of like this guy's, but not quite. I was escaping the value of the text area as soon as it was posted, and then working with it. I've removed that function and tested it, everything works properly now but, there's got to be a way I can still prevent sql injection AND have this work.

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this is an old issue but I had the same problem but discovered I was using mysql_real_escape_string on the contents of tinymce twice. I removed the second occurrence of the escape and it is fixed.